# Dataframe groupby or stack/pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
          date  symbol_id  value
0   2015-01-12        abc    345
1   2015-01-12        xyz    465
2   2015-01-13        abc   7874
3   2015-01-13        xyz     23
4   2015-01-14        abc    899
5   2015-01-14        xyz   1483
```

I need to transform this dataframe into the something like the following:

```
                symbol_id  value  symbol_id  value
    date        
0   2015-01-12        abc    345        xyz    465
1   2015-01-13        abc   7874        xyz     23
2   2015-01-14        abc    899        xyz   1483
```

So basically what needs to be done is that I need one date per row, with the corresponding symbol_id and its value. However I need the index to be integers (as per the example). The index must not be dates.

I've tried to do:

```
df.groupby('symbol_id')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

However I get an error: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects`

I think something like stack or pivot is the answer but I can't get it working.

Comment: Not quite the output you want but are you after: `df.pivot(index='date', columns='symbol_id')`?

Comment: Yes that's great. I just needed to do a reset_index after that because I need an integer index, then it's all good. Thanks!

Comment: regarding your error, a `groupby` object is essentially metadata about how to perform the groupby, you need to call a function on it in order to generate the df, it is on the df that you call `reset_index`

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the clarification.